# How to slow down user input?

Tags: c#, xna

My update function gets called like 60 times a second, and the player is meant to move in 32 pixel steps on my grid, so the player moves very quickly, i want a way to only recieve certain key inputs every like 10 frames, and still have my game run at 60fps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can

- require user to do full keyboard clicks with releasing each key
- have user's position to be sort-of float instead of int where whole part represents grid steps. While user tries to move in particular direction it will move with some defined speed (like 2 per sec) and when float position becomes next cell player jumps
- you can require player to stay in particular cell some given amount of time (like .5 seconds) - thus definind speed how fast it moves.

Comment: Whats a good method to keep the player in a cell for 0.5 secs? i looked at members of gameTime and i can't see any of use there

Comment: I don't think there are any specific members for it. I'd add something like "LastMovedTime" to a player object and make sure not to move the player till LastMovedTime+CellTime < TotalGameTime.

Comment: gee.. what a great idea.  Why didn't I think of that.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to keep time on when a key was pressed.  There isn't a way to slow down the speed of the input system, so you have to fake it yourself.  Here is some pseudocode to get you started.

```
// See if the key is currently down
if (KeyIsDown(key))
{
  if (gameTime.TotalGameTime >= nextTime)
  {
    // Move the character, and indicate that you want to wait another second for movement.
    moveTheCharacter();
    nextTime = gameTime.TotalGameTime + 1;
  }
}
```

The main advantage of this approach is that it will always be based on time as opposed to the framerate of your game.  So if you drop frames for some reason your character will still move at the same speed.